# Python: get zip file from url, extract, and save files / images to server

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, zip

I am getting a zipfile from a url.

Extracted, it has the following format:

- parent_folder

  - my_file.csv
  - image_folder

    - my_image.jpg

I want to save this, extracted, to my server. Before saving, I want to 1) alter the name of parent_folder and 2) insert extra text into the .csv file

I have tried various combinations of code trying to figure out what is going on:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib import urlopen
from PIL import Image

url = urlopen("path.zip")
z = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read()))

# z= z.extractall() # not sure I need this?

for line in z.open("my_file.csv").readlines():
     print line  
     # this does print so I could open a new file and write to it. Is that what I do?

img= Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(z.open("image_folder/my_image.jpg")))
# error: must be convertible to a buffer, not ZipExtFile
# I don't know how to GET the image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: `z.open("image_folder/my_image.jpg")` gives a `ZipExtFile` object, while `cStringIO.StringIO` wants a buffer.

Solution: Try this:

```
img= Image.open(cStringIO.StringIO(z.open("image_folder/my_image.jpg").read()))
```